# Oracle Apex 18.1 editing IR

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

When I try to edit more than one row in an Interactive Grid, some rows are deleted. I use Oracle Apex 18.1

[Here is Apex IR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdKnl.png)

Answer (score 0):

If query (that the IG is based on) contains a `WHERE` clause, and if you modify columns that are used in that `WHERE` clause, maybe they don't satisfy the condition so IR doesn't display them any more. They aren't actually "deleted", you just don't see them.

Comment: But ,they are actually deleted from the Database @Littlefoot

Comment: If so, it's a bug in Apex 18.1. Report it to the authors.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Apex has not reported any known bugs in the release notes for APEX 18.1.0:

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/apex/known-issues-v181.html

**The issue might be due to:**

(1) On Click of Save the saved record must disappear because you might have not have returned the primary key in the Interactive Grid Processing Section.

(2) There might be some **WHERE** conditions in the query that might not satisfy the condition so the rows(s) might disappear.

(3) There might be some CODE written in the Database to delete the rows based on some condition (or) there might be some Triggers in the table that deletes the rows based on some condition.

(4)Installation Issue (Please check the Installation LOG), consider this point as the last approach.